# How do I write a shortcode that opens and closes?

Tags: plugin-development, shortcode

I want to have a shortcode like this:

```
[readmore]Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit...[/readmore]
```

Answer (score 3):

I found the correct way:

```
function readmore_link($defaults,$between_the_tags){
    ...

    $output = 'This is between the shortcode tags:';
    $output .= $between_the_tags;

    return $output;
}
add_shortcode('readmore', 'readmore_link');
```

More about enclosing shortcodes on [WP Codex: Shortcode API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API#Enclosing_vs_self-closing_shortcodes)